# Exceded maximum insert size of 16,000,000 bytes + mongoDB + ruby

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have an application where I'm using mongodb as a database for storing record the ruby wrapper for mongodb I'm using is mongoid

Now everything was working fine until I hit a above error

**Exceded maximum insert size of 16,000,000 bytes**

Can any pin point how to get rid of errors.

I'm running a mongodb server which does not have a configuration file (no configuration was provide with mongodb source file)

Can anyone help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have hit the maximum limit of a single document in MongoDB. 
If you save large data files in MongoDB, use [GridFs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS) instead.
If your document has too many subdocuments, consider splitting it and use relations instead of nesting.

Comment: Thanks but now how do you configure mongodb  to use gridfs and what the upper limit for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The limit of 16MB data per document is a  very well known limitation.
Use GridFS for storing arbitrary binary data of arbitrary size + metadata.